# MySQL: Select 5 actions by 10 most recently active users

Tags: mysql

Assuming a table called "activity" with the columns:

whenItHappened datetime, who text, what text

I want to select the 5 most recent actions by the 10 most recently active users, in the last hour.

So far I have:

```
SELECT * FROM activity
JOIN (
    SELECT who FROM activity
    WHERE whenItHappened >= (CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    GROUP BY (who)
    ORDER BY whenItHappened DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS unique_recent_users
ON unique_recent_users.who = activity.who;
```

This does a good job of selecting all activity by the last ten most recently active users. However, I can't figure out a good way to limit it to just the last five actions from each user.

If I put a LIMIT clause at the end of the SQL statement it will only return five results total. The desired behavior is that if there were ten users active in the last hour it should show 50 actions, five for each of those recently active users.

I can easily do this by using PHP to one query to get the most recent 10 users, then 5 actions from each of them, but I can't help but thinking there must be some elegant way to do this natively in MySQL.

**Edit:** (Via Darrrrren's link I found this solution which allows me to select the 5 most recent actions from all users. I'm not sure what the performance will be like though as the table gets larger.)

```
select whenItHappened, who, what
from activity
where (
   select count(*) from activity as a
   where a.who = activity.who and a.whenItHappened <= activity.whenItHappened
) <= 5;
```

Comment: Not an answer but should get you on your way: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this elegantly in MySQL.  One method that works requires a self-join:

```
select a.*
from (SELECT who
      FROM activity
      WHERE whenItHappened >= (CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
      GROUP BY (who)
      ORDER BY whenItHappened DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) AS unique_recent_users join
     Activity a
     on unique_recent_users.who = activity.who join
     Activity a2
     on a2.who = a.who and
        a2.whenItHappened >= a.WhenItHappened
group by a.id
having count(*) <= 5
```

(Note that this is using the Hidden Columns "feature" of MySQL to return columns not included in the `group by` statement.)

If you happen to have a counter in the activity table per user, then you could use this counter to get the most recent five.  If you want the 50 most recent activities, regardless of user, you can do that as well.  And, if you were using almost any other database, then ranking functions (`row_number()` in particular) would solve the problem elegantly.

Comment: Very interesting I'll try that out. Also from Darrrrrrren's link I found a technique which seems to work although I'm not sure what the performance will be like as the table gets larger. `select whenItHappened, who, what
from activity
where (
   select count(*) from activity as a
   where a.who = activity.who and a.whenItHappened <= activity.whenItHappened
) <= 2;`  What do you think about this technique?

Comment: I find the documentation on user variables ambiguous as to whether they are guaranteed to work for enumerating rows (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html).  In practice, they seem to work and that method should be faster on large amounts of data.  In either case, you should have an index on (who, WhenItHappened) to optimize performance.

Comment: The specific line in the documentation is:  "As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed."  However, the examples seem to refer to the variable used in different expressions, so it is not clear if the advice applies to the variable being used in a single expression.

Comment: Okay interesting. I have indexes on who and whenItHappened already. I was not familiar with those guidelines about user variables.